# vector identifier isn't defined but it is?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm declaring a vector of a certain type;

```
std::vector<CBullet> m_vBullets;
```

and I'm looking to return the vector to assign to another vector later on;

```
std::vector<CBullet> getVectorBullet()
{
    std::vector<CBullet> c;
    c = m_vBullets;
    return c;
}
```

When I try and assign `c` to `m_vBullets` I get the following error;

```
2   IntelliSense: identifier "m_vBullets" is undefined
```

Any reason why?

Comment: My wild guess would be that `m_vBullets` is a data member, and `getVectorBullet()` is defined outside of the class, i.e. it is a non-member function. But more context is needed.

Comment: where is m_vBullets defined?  If it is a class member then getVectorBullet needs to be a class member as well - if it is defined outside the class it needs class scope.

Comment: Also, why aren't you doing `return m_vBullets;` instead?

Comment: I blame not enough sleep, sorry to waste your time guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined.

Assuming m_vBullets is a class member then I guess what you meant to write is

```
std::vector<CBullet> YourClassNameHere::getVectorBullet()
{
    std::vector<CBullet> c;
    c = m_vBullets;
    return c;
}
```

Obviously replace `YourClassNameHere` with your actual class name.

Also this function can be simplified, it's just the same as

```
std::vector<CBullet> YourClassNameHere::getVectorBullet()
{
    return m_vBullets;
}
```

there's no obvious need to copy the vector before you return it since returning the vector will copy it anyway.

Comment: Oh bloody nora, what a silly, silly little man. Thanks for that John.